# android: back button disappear from toolbar after the app is killed

Tags: android, back-button

I have an activity that contains a toolbar with a back button like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        style="@style/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is the toolbar style used

```
<style name="toolbar">
        <item name="navigationIcon">?attr/homeAsUpIndicator</item>
</style>
```

The back button is working as expected, but I am facing a weird error where the back button disappears only when I kill the app from recent apps or the app crashes and I reopen the app.
like the following picture [image]
but if I click on the place where the button is supposed to be is looks like the following picture
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Was it ever a darker color?
Because now I see that you may have set a toolbar back button drawable to the same color of your toolbar. You can check if you have the same problem when you change the background of the toolbar view.

One solution is to change the android:homeAsUpIndicator icon drawable in your app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/dark_back_button_drawable</item>
</style>
```

Comment: that doesn't make sense. since the app is working normally and this only happens after the app is killed. btw the color of the toolbar is light and the button itself is dark so that shouldn't be the problem. any other ideas?

Comment: You say that it happens after the app is killed, so if it is started normally it also happens? Because these are two same things: starting the app normally and after the app is killed

Comment: if it starts normally it doesn't happen. only when the app is killed or the app is crashed and restarted.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of code of the activity or/and fragment you have the toolbar and this issue happening?

Answer (score 0):

When you apply a theme to a view you have to specify the parent theme if you want the normal behavior with a specific part modified.

```xml
<style name="AppTheme.BackNavigationToolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="navigationIcon">?attr/homeAsUpIndicator</item>
</style>
```

If you decide to use the Toolbar which you get from a activity and not declare it in xml. You can just use the `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)`. If you want to read more on this check this page out: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/up-action

```kotlin
supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

If it is two activities you are navigating between then you just have to specifiy parent activity in the AndroidManifest.xml

#### Exampel

```xml
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label = "Second Activity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

More resources:
https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up